# Ubuntu Studio lost the ability to restart

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I have installed Ubuntu Studio 21.04 on a Samsung Series 5 notebook. Everything went fine and the system worked properly. A week or so ago, it lost the ability to restart. That is, if I right click on the desktop, select Leave, and select Restart, the system shuts down and does not reboot. In addition, if I open a console window, enter

sudo shutdown -r now

it proceeds to shutdown but does not restart, as requested.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Thanks... Tom.

Comment: Use `sudo reboot` to reboot from a terminal

Comment: Just tried that. No joy. Just shutdown with no reboot.